# Record audio with phone, but play record through bluetooth headset in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

Is it possible to record sound with the phone but force the playing through a bluetooth headset?

This is how I set my AVAudioSession category

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:[AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers])
```

The record is forced to use the phone mic. However, when playing the sound, it comes out from the phone too. I want the sound to be played only through the bluetooth headset.

I tried overriding the output audio port

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none)
```

but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solve. I just added the allowBluetoothA2DP option then it works.

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:[AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers])
```